# Why do you change the name of a class instance in the constructor method in Java?

Tags: java

I'm currently learning object oriented java, and I am curious why you need to change the name of the class instance in the constructor method. For example, if i am modeling a car, and i declare a boolean with the name isRunning, why do you change the name in the constructor method to isRunning = carRunning;

Sorry if this is a stupid question but thanks in advance!
Also, im brand new to the site so if theres any recommendations with anything, please feel free to let me know!

Comment: Are you referring to parameter names vs. instance variable names?  Could you include a short example to illustrate what you're referring to here?

Comment: All java is object-oriented.

Comment: @NomadMaker No, Java is mostly [object-oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), but not entirely OOP.  Neither `static` nor primitive values are OOP.

Comment: Please edit your Question for clarity so it can be re-opened, and so you can accept the Answer which seems to have worked for you. Address the first comment. This site is meant to be a repository of knowledge, not a casual chat forum.

Answer (score 3):

> why do you change the name in the constructor method to isRunning = carRunning;

You... don't. Unless you want to - java doesn't care. Pick whatever identifier you want. Style guides suggest you pick a name that makes the signatures make sense (the stuff visible from outside of your source files: The name of your class itself, and the name, parameter types, return type, and parameter names of all the public methods inside it).

One small reason is the shadowing that occurs. If you write:

```
public void foo(String bar) {
}
```

that `bar` is a parameter and it is 'scoped' to the method: That variable exists for the duration of your method and disappears immediately afterwards. Contrast to:

```
public class Foo {
   String bar;
}
```

Here `bar` is a field and it will exist the moment a `new Foo()` is created and will never disappear until that Foo is eventually garbage collected. These 2 'lifetimes' will cross paths; there will be a time when both exist, and they are **utterly separate**. Completely unrelated. Sooo, when you write `bar`, what does that mean? The 'nearest' definition 'wins', and that's what it means. Thus:

```
public class Example {
    private String foo;

    public Example(String foo) {
    }
}
```

here you have 2 different things, completely unrelated things, that by total coincidence are both named `foo`. Java is completely fine with this, but within that constructor, if you type `foo`, that refers to the parameter and not the field because it is 'closer', in the sense that if you look for `{}` and go outwards, it's closer (not in character distance, in other words).

You can still refer to the field named `foo` with `this`. So, you can write:

```
public class Example {
    private String foo;

    public Example(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

Which is fine; had you written `foo = foo;` that, obviously, does nothing. This style (with the `this.x`) is in fact **idiomatic**: It's what most java programmers do, and as a consequence, is probably what you should do. I can see how someone teaching you java wants to avoid this complication and avoid having to explain what `this.` does for now, and thus tells you to pick a different name. However, that is didactically speaking a highly suspect move. i.e. bad course / teacher / book.

Comment: The course i was going through was apart of Codecademy, which has been a helpful course that i understood up until that point. Appreciate your explanation!